# How to push struct type variable in standard stack in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, stack

Code Should i use &g on calling or *s in stack declaration?:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

main(){
    stack<node> s;
    struct node *g;
    g = new node;
    s.push(g);
}
```

Comment: s/`stack<node> s;`/`stack<node*> s;`

Comment: Another way without changing the `std::stack` type: `s.push(node());`

Comment: Neither. Check out the [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

Stack push() either copy the object, either move it. If you do not need share access to node objects, put them (not pointers) to stack via move semantic:

```
std::stack<node> st;
st.push(node());
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/push

Answer (score -1):

I think you have an error at `s.push(g)` because type of `g`is `node*`, so you cannot put it into `stack<node>`. I think you should declare `stack < node*>` because it's easy to use with `new` operation.

Comment: That something is _easier to use_, rarely is a good reason to use it.